# CSS animation difference under HTTP and HTTPS protocol

Tags: css, https, css-animations

```
@-webkit-keyframes resetFade{0{opacity:0}100%{opacity:0}}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in{0{opacity:0}50%{opacity:.5}100%{opacity:1}}
#div1 {-webkit-animation:resetFade 300ms ease-in 0ms 1, fade-in 300ms ease-in 250ms 1}
```

Check the code above, assume the `opacity` of `div` is 1 at beginning. The two animations behave differently under HTTP and HTTPS protocol in *Safari*.

Under HTTP protocol the `opacity` of `div` will first become 0 because of keyframe `resetFade` and then after 250ms delay of keyframe `fade-in`, the `opacity` will change from 0 to 1.

During this process, when the `resetFade` key frame finish at 300ms, it will not affect the opacity to recover from 0 to 1 because the keyframe `fade-in` is still in process.

However, under HTTPS protocol, when keyframe `resetFade` is done, it will recover the `opacity` from 0 to 1 which will look like a flickering because keyframe `fade-in` is still in process to animate `opacity` from 0 to 1.

It is difficult to understand why HTTP and HTTPS will have affect on rendering. Does anybody have any insight?

Comment: keyframes is pretty well supported now, yet you are still relying on the proprietary -webkit- implementation. Each of those -webkit- instructions should be followed by the (now standard) implementation, by dropping the -webkit-. This will allow a browser that needs the webkit version to use and the those that support the standard will use that. Your problem may be linked to the webkit implementation.

Comment: _“It is difficult to understand why HTTP and HTTPS will have affect on rendering”_ – it shouldn’t have any. Have you checked the console to see if any external resources were blocked maybe? Otherwise, unless you show a live example where we can compare the HTTP and HTTPS version, this is hardly reproducible.